# Route 53 DNS Unstable

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

My DNS works keeps dropping in and out (working and then not working).

Route 53 Settings:

[image: Step 1]

GoDaddy Zone File:

```
MYSITE.COM. 3600    IN  SOA ns03.domaincontrol.com. dns.jomax.net (
                2015120200
                28800
                7200
                604800
                600
                )

; A Records
@   600 IN  A   198.185.159.144
@   600 IN  A   198.185.159.145
@   600 IN  A   198.49.23.144
@   600 IN  A   198.49.23.145

; CNAME Records
email   3600    IN  CNAME   email.secureserver.net
ftp 3600    IN  CNAME   @
rtwzezashxkbwtjtj4p5    3600    IN  CNAME   verify.squarespace.com
www 3600    IN  CNAME   ext-sq.squarespace.com

; MX Records
@   3600    IN  MX  10  mailstore1.secureserver.net
@   3600    IN  MX  0   smtp.secureserver.net

; NS Records
@   3600    IN  NS  ns-1478.awsdns-56.org
@   3600    IN  NS  ns-1617.awsdns-10.co.uk
@   3600    IN  NS  ns-329.awsdns-41.com
@   3600    IN  NS  ns-687.awsdns-21.net
@   3600    IN  NS  ns03.domaincontrol.com
@   3600    IN  NS  ns04.domaincontrol.com
```

I originally had the A record that are in GoDaddy also in Route53 settings but removing them seemed to help a little bit although it is still dropping out.

I have also tried using CNAME records for the api, teamcity and octopus subdomains.

Just not sure at all what is broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that this is not how you use Route 53 (or any other DNS provider) with Go Daddy as your domain registrar.

Your domain is still using Go Daddy, not Route 53, as evidenced by a "whois" lookup.  The real question is really how it could be working at all.

You don't want to create `NS` records at Go Daddy.  You need to actually switch the authoritative name servers to use the 4 name servers that were assigned by Route 53 when you created the hosted zone.

https://www.godaddy.com/help/set-custom-nameservers-for-domains-registered-with-us-12317

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two issues here:

1. You have two SOA. In Route53 your SOA points to an AWS server. In Godaddy, it points to Godaddy server. SOA must be identical in all nameservers. See http://rscott.org/dns/soa.html for additional info.
2. In AWS, CNAME records look wrong: They point to domains relative to the main domain, but those domains are not defined (i.e. `ext-sq.squarespace.com.ratingkit.com` appears in AWS but it's not defined. In contrast `ext-sq.squarespace.com` looks OK)

Comment: Thanks, the CName records were wrong too.